# How you do you remove a view from an outlet by pressing the back button in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

With the current version of the ember router, you can define a route handler like so:

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('home', {into: "application", outlet: "body"});
  }
});
```

Older builds would allow you to disconnect a view from an outlet on the exit state of a route like this:

```
exit: function(router){
  router.get('applicationController').disconnectOutlet('chatroom');
}
```

However, as of router v2, the disconnectOutlet method no longer works (I assume because it was lumped together with the connectOutlet(s) method(s).

So how do you disconnect a view now? Are you supposed to render a blank template into the outlet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should actually "just work".

On exiting a route, [Ember tears down the view](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L7-L9). However, `exit` is no longer a public hook, and because you are not calling `super`, your incorrect guess about how to tear down the view is clobbering the built-in behavior!

If you remove the `exit` call, everything should work as you expect.

Comment: @Yehuda In what version of Emberjs, exit is no longer a public hook. With the current master version of Emebrjs, i'm still using exit in my Routes.

Comment: @ken it still **exists** but is not public. If you use it, please make sure you call super.